# Getting a random element in a QuerySet - Python Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I have the following query in Django:

```
vms = VM.objects.filter(vmtype=vmtype,
                        status__in=['I', 'R'])
                     .annotate(num_jobs=Count('job'))
                     .order_by('num_jobs')
```

it will return a QuerySet of vms based on the number of jobs running in each VM. Please notice that `num_jobs` is not a field in the `VM` object (model). This would return a query set such as the number of jobs is
[0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5].
Doing `vms.first()` will for sure return me the vm with least number of jobs, but it could not be the only. From all the `vms` with the least number of jobs, I want to return a random between them, not just the first. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: do you want a random choice only from records where `num_jobs = min(num_jobs)`?

Comment: @thebjorn yes...

Answer (score 1):

You can order_by with `num_jobs` and `?`, which will order the `VM` objects with number of jobs with random order of objects with same number of jobs.

```
vms = VM.objects.filter(vmtype=vmtype,
                        status__in=['I', 'R'])
                     .annotate(num_jobs=Count('job'))
                     .order_by('num_jobs', '?')
```

Then you can get a random object every time you call `vms.filter(num_jobs=<any_number>).first()` (or without the filter).

This query worked for me on PostgreSQL database. The query it generated (except for the filter expression):

```sql
SELECT "myapp_vm"."id", "myapp_vm"."status", "myapp_vm"."vm_type",
 COUNT("myapp_vm"."job") AS "num_jobs" FROM "myapp_vm" GROUP BY "myapp_vm"."id", RANDOM() ORDER BY "myapp_vm"."num_jobs" ASC, RANDOM() ASC'
```